# Asana API - GET all Attachments in a Workspace (+ the view_url param)

Tags: node.js, asana, asana-api

I'm wondering if there's a way to get all attachment view_urls for an Asana workspace. The company I work for is looking to do a sweep of their Asana attachments to make sure everything that should be living in a proper file store (i.e. Google Drive) isn't lost in a completed Asana task.

I've been referencing the Asana API docs, but it doesn't seem like this is something that is particularly common - and I'm hoping it's not impossible (or, prohibitively time-consuming).

I've been hitting the API via cURL, which has been good for simple calls, but I'm finding it to be a bit limiting for detailed requests.

The node wrapper has made certain calls easier (retrieving all tasks based on assignee, for instance); but has pretty significant limitations when it comes to attachments.

I've been trying to get a proof-of-concept working, but haven't had much luck.

Currently the node implementation looks like this:

```
let asana = require("asana")
let client = 
asana.Client.create().useAccessToken('0/##########################(this 
is properly populated, normally))

client.users.me()
  .then(user => {
    const userId = user.id;

    const workspaceId = user.workspaces[0].id;
    //this part works fine
    return client.tasks.findAll({
        workspace: workspaceId,
        assignee: userId,
        opt_fields: 'id,name'
    });
  })
  .then(response => {
    //this is working as expected
    console.log(response.data)
    //this is working as expected too...
    let taskArray = response.data
    taskArray.forEach(task => {
        console.log(task.id)
    })
    return taskArray.id
  }
).catch(e => {
    console.log(e.value.errors)
})
```

That feeds back an array of taskIds that I've been then running through this:

```
tasks.forEach(task => {
    client.attachments.findByTask(task.id)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)

        return client.attachments.findById(response.data.id, {
            // I can't seem to retrieve the urls...
            opt_fields: 'view_url,download_url'
        })
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - was doing a lot of things that I didn't need to be doing in the iteration posted above. Ultimately, there was still a bit of work that had to be done manually - but nothing particularly time-consuming. Here's what worked:

```
client.users.me()
.then(user => {
    const userId = user.id;

    const workspaceId = user.workspaces[0].id;
    //this part works fine
    return client.tasks.findByProject(support, {
        opt_fields: 'id,name'
    });
})
.then(collection => {
    //this is working as expected too...
    let taskArray = collection.stream().on('data', task => {
        console.log(task.id)
        client.attachments.findByTask(task.id, {
            opt_fields: 'id, view_url, download_url, permanent_url'
        }).then(attachment => {
            console.log(attachment.data)
            return attachment.data
        })
        })
    return taskArray.json()
}
).then(tasks => {
    console.log(tasks.permanent_url)
}


).catch(e => {
    console.log(e.value)
})
```